# trigger javascript function using c#

Tags: c#, javascript, html

I have to write a c# class that gets an html page's content (the page is public) and trigger a javascript function that downloads a file.

My goal is to download the file and save it in a folder

The page is a public html page that does not require login.

The link looks like this :

```
href="javascript:__doPostBack(&#39;lbtSpreadsheet&#39;,&#39;&#39;)" style="font-weight: 700">Export Results</a>
```

the doPostBack function contains the following code:

```
function __doPostBack(eventTarget, eventArgument) {
if (!theForm.onsubmit || (theForm.onsubmit() != false)) {
    theForm.__EVENTTARGET.value = eventTarget;
    theForm.__EVENTARGUMENT.value = eventArgument;
    theForm.submit();
}
```

when you click the link manually, it submits the form and returns an excel sheet, the download dialog box opens to ask you where you need to save it.

I want to do this automatically to get the excel sheet and then process it.

I found out that I can find the links on a page like this:

```
HtmlWeb hw = new HtmlWeb();
HtmlDocument doc = hw.Load(/* url */);
foreach(HtmlNode link in      doc.DocumentElement.SelectNodes("//a[@href]"))
{

}
```

but how can I trigger the javascript in the link and save the file returned?

Thank you

Comment: Is your C# app a wesite or other type of app? If webstie, do you want to save the file client side or server side?

Comment: If I get you correctly you want to simulate the file download when the page loads without the `Export Results` link triggering the file download, right?

Comment: This is not a web app and the page I want to download the file from is not on my server. I am actually creating a scheduled task that will run every week and access this page, download the file and process it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can. C# server side web clients such as HtmlWeb or WebClient only understand HTTP/HTML, they aren't full-fledged web browsers capable of executing javascript the same way that IE, Firefox or Chrome could.

Comment: If this Javascript is doing a POST, can I use one of those classes to perform what the javascript function is doing:  Send a POST after passing  it the data and then get the file and save it ?

Comment: Yes, although unless you have access to the other page's code, it would be hard to "reverse engineer" it and figure out what it was doing.  Do you have access to that code, or to the people who wrote it?

Comment: No I don't have access to the code or people. But the page is static and the link always calls this function.

Comment: That's going to be really tricky then, because that javascript function causes the page to POST, and then some server side code executes to give you the file. That server side code is what you need to execute, not the javascript, but you don't really have access to do that programmatically from a webclient.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the file download to start automatically during the `onload` of the page without the `Export Results` link triggering the file download then you can write the below js script that calls your js function `__doPostBack` which in turn does the form submission.

```
window.onload = function() {
   __doPostBack (param1, param2);
};
```

Or as your question title says `'trigger javascript function using c#'` then you can access Javascript function from C# code using `ScriptManager` class which is part of System.Web.UI

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this.Page, this.GetType(), "FileDownload", "Javascript:__doPostBack (param1, param2);", true);
 }
```

Comment: No, this link is not in my asp.net page, It's a page on a public site that I need to access. See my comment above.